# TikZ: bullet points on both sides of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Here's a MWE of a diagram I'm working on for a paper:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    item/.style={circle, fill, minimum width=2pt, inner sep=0pt},
    group/.style={rectangle, draw},
]

% group 1
\node (item1)      [item, label=left:item 1] {};
\node (item2)      [item, label=left:item 2, below=12pt of item1] {};

% group 2
\node (item3)      [item, label=right:item 3, right=60pt of item1] {};
\node (item4)      [item, label=right:item 4, below=12pt of item3] {};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
% groups
\node (group1) [fit=(item1) (item2), group, label=above:group 1, xshift=-27pt, minimum width=80pt, inner sep=12pt] {};
\node (group2) [fit=(item3) (item4), group, label=above:group 2, xshift=27pt, minimum width=80pt, inner sep=12pt] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are several groups (drawn as rectangles), each of which contains some items.
Each item is next to a bullet point.

[image: TikZ graph]

**My question**: how can I duplicate the bullet points on both sides of the items (that is, when they're on the right side, I would like them simultaneously on the left side too)?
Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO it's done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting each line in an 80pt node `lineitem`, and using `path picture` to create the two circles.

EDIT: We can locate the points with
`([xshift=-2pt]item1.east)` and by modifying `outer sep=2pt`, to `outer sep=0pt`,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
%item/.style={circle, fill,red, minimum width=2pt, inner sep=0pt},
lineitem/.style={
        %draw,
        minimum width=80pt,
        inner sep=0pt, 
        outer sep=0pt,%<-- modif
        path picture = {
            \draw [fill] ([xshift=2pt]path picture bounding box.west) circle (1pt);
            \draw [fill] ([xshift=-2pt]path picture bounding box.east) circle (1pt);
                }
},
group/.style={rectangle, draw},
]

% group 1
\node [lineitem]                        (item1) {item 1};
\node [lineitem,below=12pt of item1]    (item2) {item 2};

% group 2
\node [lineitem, right=60pt of item1]   (item3) {item 3};
\node [lineitem, below=12pt of item3]   (item4) {item 4};


\begin{scope}[on background layer]
% groups
\node (group1) [fit=(item1) (item2), group, label=above:group 1minimum,inner sep=12pt] {};
\node (group2) [fit=(item3) (item4), group, label=above:group 2,inner sep=12pt] {};
\end{scope}


\draw ([xshift=-2pt]item1.east)--([xshift=2pt]item4.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Hgd.png]

Comment: Thanks Pascal, looks great! What if wanted to draw edges between groups (there's actually more than 2), using the left bullet points for some edges and the right bullet points for others?

Comment: @Charlie Vanaret I made the modification in the answer

Comment: gorgeous, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would use labels for the bullets using the the `mid west` and `mid east` anchors to align them vertically. By making the name of these labels depending on `\tikzlastnode`, they automatically get named according to the name of their parent node.

I'm using matrices in the example below which names the nodes `<matrix name>-<row>-<column>` and thus the bullets are named `<matrix name>-<row>-<column>-w` and ``---e` but the above applies to every named node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{
  group with itemize/.style={
    matrix of nodes, draw, nodes={itemize, text depth=+0pt}},
  itemize/.style={
    append after command={
      [every node/.code=] % empty “every node”
        nodealso[
          label={[every item=weast,xshift=+-.15em]mid west:},
          label={[every item=ewest,xshift=+ .15em]mid east:}](\tikzlastnode)}},
  every item/.style 2 args={
    shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt,
    minimum size=+.6ex, fill, name=\tikzlastnode-#1, anchor=#2}}
\begin{document}
\tikz
 \node[group with itemize, "group 1"]                  (group1) {
    item 1 \\
    item 2 \\
  }
  node[group with itemize, "group 2", right=of group1] (group2) {
    Foo Long Text Bar  \\
    item 4 \\
  }
  (group1-1-1-e) edge[red] (group2-2-1-w)
  ;
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

Code (only tikz - no library):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at(4,3) () {group1};
        \node at(9,3) () {group2};
        \draw (2,1) rectangle (6,2.5);
        \draw (7,1) rectangle (11,2.5);
        \filldraw[draw=white] (2.5,2) circle(2pt) -- (5.5,2) circle(2pt) node[pos=.5,fill=white] () {item 1};
        \filldraw[draw=white] (2.5,1.5) circle(2pt) -- (5.5,1.5) circle(2pt) node[pos=.5,fill=white] () {item 2};
        \filldraw[draw=white] (7.5,2) circle(2pt) -- (10.5,2) circle(2pt) node[pos=.5,fill=white] () {item 3};
        \filldraw[draw=white] (7.5,1.5) circle(2pt) -- (10.5,1.5) circle(2pt) node[pos=.5,fill=white] () {item 4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can make the picture more compact - change the coordinate's nodes.

Comment: Thanks Raffaele, I went for Pascal's solution :)

Comment: @CharlieVanaret No problem - be happy.